# ActionScript (Flash) Визуализация музыки

Tags: flash, actionscript, аудио

Про SoundMixer.computeSpectrum и equalizer знаю, "столбики" прыгающие под музыку вроде понял как делать.
А вот как создать вот такие волны? Точнее просто скажите, возможно ли это вообще на флеше и намекните что нужно для этого знать.
Может хотя бы подскажите по каким тегам гуглить всякое подобное добро? А то хочу как нибудь для сайта сделать на главной лупы и по оригинальничать в этом деле. Кстати, может это на html можно реализовать? Во всяком случае видел два совсем других визуализатора на нем...
[image: Лучше скриншота не нашел..]